# Same Memory Address After Initialization

Tags: c++, random

I was messing around trying to create random numbers without rand() (just cuz I like to try stuff). Using an online compiler, this works great:

```
#include <iostream>

int randNum()
{
    unsigned int x;
    size_t y = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&x);
    return ((y >> 16) & 0x0000FFFF);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = randNum();
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it locally on my computer, though...not so much. Every time I compile and run this, it assigns x to the same memory address.

I can understand why the online compiler would give me a new memory address every time, but why not on my local machine?

Comment: That's way far from a random number generation algorithm.

Comment: The type `size_t` is not guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer. Use `intptr_t` instead.

Comment: Please define 'random'. For example, `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4` is a 100% random sequence.

Comment: It's up to the platform where your programs base address and stack are located.  It's perfectly reasonable for this to be the same every time.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this is random in any useful sense to begin with?

Comment: When the memory address is different each time, it's pretty random. Sucks I can't get that to work on a standalone machine though.

Comment: With undefined behavior anything can happen. This is in no way a good random number generator.

Comment: ***Every time I compile and run this, it assigns x to the same memory address.*** I would expect that somehow you have ASLR disabled on your local machine. http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/address-space-layout-randomization-ASLR

Comment: Even on a platform where running the executable twice produces different (non-random) values, calling that function multiple times in a row will produce the **same values**. Try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: A reasonable implementation might put `x` on the stack, and if the stack size changes between calls (e.g. by storing the result of previous calls) then `&x` might change. But I agree that the values will still be highly correlated when not identical

Comment: @MSalters -- that's why I said "multiple times in a row". Yes, there are lots of details of stack management that **might** affect the result, but that's all noise for a beginner.

Comment: What kind of machine / OS are you running, @Steve?

Comment: @HumphreyWinnebago MSI GT70 Dominator with Windows 10 Pro

Comment: What CPU and what compiler? Any special compiler flags?

And for the online compiler, any idea what OS and compiler they're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a little background. Each program gets fake RAM addresses from the OS. It's called the virtual address space, and it allows the process to behave as if it has the entire memory to itself. The process doesn't have to worry about conflicting with other running processes. When it tries to access a memory location, the OS translates the virtual address to the real "physical" address. If you're interested in this, you should look up page tables.

A process has 3 main memory areas. The stack, the heap, and the text. The stack keeps your function stack as well as local variables defined in those functions, such as your unsigned int x.

Your randNum is simply returning the current location of the bottom of the stack. (btw, that is a security risk). With your simple test, randNum will always return the same result, because the address of x is based on the stack.

Ok so you might be wondering why the stack base always starts in the same place. Although it has a little wiggle room, the stack is always at the top (high numbers) end of your address space, for example, 0xBFFF0000, and it grows "downward", towards low numbers. When you do the right-shift (y >> 16) you're actually looking at the least varying part of the address, which just so happens to be the page index, the part that can be shared by hundreds of variables living on the same page.

Things that can affect the location of the stack base:

- Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), a hacking countermeasure. Doesn't necessarily re-randomize every time you start a process.
- environment variables, which can come from outside the process. Won't necessarily change very often and depend on the machine.
- CPU, OS, compiler...
- more???

I would bet that's what happening with the online compiler is that each time you're compiling on a different machine. And each time you run, it's running on a different machine. With many people accessing the server at the same time, perhaps it's having an effect on environment variables? Whereas when you're running on your local machine, things are relatively quiet.

So I want to say that it was a great idea, and even though it doesn't work, I hope you learned something interesting.

Comment: While there are many poor parts to this answer, the biggest reason I downvoted it is that you contradict yourself. You are correct to note that "virtual address space allows the process to behave as if it has the entire memory" but then speculate that there might be "many people accessing the server". True, but they get their own processes with their own virtual address spaces.

Answer (score 4):

> I can understand why the online compiler would give me a new memory address every time, but why not on my local machine?

Short answer: because there's nothing in the Standard that guarantees that the memory address will be either the same or different every time. It depends on where (platform, OS) you're running the program, how you compiled it, and a thousand more factors.

Do **not** rely on things like this in your code. Most importantly, if you need random number generation for a real project, use `<random>` or PCG.

Comment: I use std::mt19937, like I said though - I was just messing around since I noticed the memory address was random with the online compiler. Led me to questions about memory allocation during compile time and run time.