# Why does the address of my variable remain the same after deleting the executable file and rerunning it on VS Code?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, compilation, operating-system, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int *ptr = &a;
    cout << ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

On deleting this code's executable file on VS Code and rerunning it, I'm getting the same value for the `ptr` variable, which means that the address location of the variable `a` remains the same. How is this possible, however, since the compilation is taking place once again, so shouldn't resource allocation also take place again and hence the address of the variable `a` (and the value of `ptr`) be different this time?

Comment: It has nothing with recompilation. Local variables are stored in stack memory. New run had a new stack, and the fact local variable had same address in new run is just a coincidence:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858525/same-memory-address-after-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Even though you recompiled the code, the new binary produced by the compiler should be identical to the original binary. Therefore, you are running the same binary twice. `a` lives on the stack, and since you are running the same binary twice, `a` is likely to be allocated at the same address on the stack. Thus, it is possible that `a` will have the same address and therefore `ptr` will have the same value.